# Data from main table does not populate the input date field of a modal form

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, model-view-controller, c#-3.0

Data in input date field(called ITEnterDate) of a modal form is not showing, although data in all the other fields is populating.  If I make the field in the modal an input text then data shows. Although, it has to be an input date so that user can select from a date picker type of thing.  What am I doing wrong?

FYI, the functioning of it:  I click on edit for a record on the main table and then a modal form opens up with all the fields populated with data from main table.

MORE INFO:
For example, the value of Enter Date of one of the records on the main form is 8/2/2020, which is stored in a SQL column of type date.

Here is my code:

MODEL

```
public string ITEnterDate { get; set;
```

JAVASCRIPT TO LOAD DATA IN THE MAIN TABLE

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    loadData();
})

function loadData() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "/Tickets/ListITTasks",
        type: "GET",
        contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (result) {
            var html = '';
            $.each(result, function (key, item) {
                html += '<tr>';
                html += '<td>' + item.ITNumber + '</td>';
                html += '<td>' + item.ITEnterDate + '</td>';
                ......

             html += '<td><a href="#" onclick="return getbyTicketNumber(' + item.ITNumber +             ')">Edit</a> | <a href="#" onclick="DeleteItTask(' + item.ITNumber + ')">Delete</a></td>';
                html += '</tr>';
            });
            $('.tbody').html(html);
        },
        error: function (errormessage) {
            alert(errormessage.responseText);
        }
    });
}
```

JAVASCRIPT TO GET DATA FROM MAIN TABLE AND POPULATE THE MODAL FIELDS WITH IT

```
function getbyTicketNumber(TicketNumber) {
    $('#ITEnterDate').css('border-color', 'lightgrey');
    .....

    $.ajax({
        url: "/Tickets/GetTaskByTicketNumber/" + TicketNumber,
        typr: "GET",
        contentType: "application/json;charset=UTF-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (result) {
            $('#ITNum').val(result.ITNumber);
            $('#ITEnterDate').val(result.ITEnterDate);
            .....

            $('#myModal').modal('show');
            $('#btnUpdate').show();
            $('#btnAddItTask').hide();
        },
        error: function (errormessage) {
            alert(errormessage.responseText);
        }
    });
    return false;
}
```

CONTROLLER

```
public JsonResult GetTaskByTicketNumber(int id)
        {
            HelpDeskDBHandle hdDB = new HelpDeskDBHandle();
            var ITNumber = hdDB.GetITTasksList().Find(x => x.ITNumber.Equals(id));
            return Json(ITNumber, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

MODAL FORM

```
<div class="modal-body">
                <form>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="ITEnterDate">Enter Date</label>
                        <input type="date" class="form-control" id="ITEnterDate"                                                             placeholder="Enter Date" />
                    </div>
                    .......

                </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution. The input date needed a data formatted as YYYY-MM-DD, therefore I added the following code to the DataReader:

```
ITEnterDate = String.Format("{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", sdr["ITEnterDate"])
```

Answer (score 0):

$('.tbody').html(html);
are you sure that class '.tbody' is not confused with element 'tbody'?

Comment: I would not think so as when I change the input type to text, instead of date, the Enter Date field gets populated.  Plus all other fields get populated.